# How can I calculate a spring's constant, using its characteristics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, spring

I want to construct a device for a school project, so I need some springs of specific constants $k$. I found some companies that can construct the springs, but they need their dimensions. I want to ask if I can use the $k$ to calculate the number of the spirals, the gap between them and the material that the wire must be made of, to take a spring of the desirable constant $k$, because the Hooke's law isn't very helpful at this time.

Comment: There are many online calculators; [here](https://www.acxesspring.com/spring-constant-calculator.html), for example. Can you really not find the spring you need at a supplier of machine parts such as McMaster-Carr?

Comment: Panos, you have more flexibility on this issue than you may realize.  If you take a spring with a certain k value and cut it in half, each half will have twice the k value of the original spring.  This means that when you order your springs, if the k value is too low, you can easily get the k value that you want by adjusting the spring length.

Comment: Yes, but I need a spring of certain dimensions and  a certain k value, in order to construct my device. So, I need an equation to determine some things,  such as the material of the wire, the number of spirals and the gap betwwen them. I can't just cut the spring, because when I put it on the device, it will exercise power, as it will be not in its natural length.

Comment: Basically, I want to find out if there is a mathematical formula with which I can calculate the constant k using the spring's dimensions and material. I don't want to calculate it by the force and displacement from Hooke's law.